# Get last day of week of a given date

Tags: python-3.x, date, calendar, dayofweek

Given any day of the year, such as today, I would have the last day of the current week.

For example, current day is 2021-12-27 (Monday), so the last day of this week is 2022-01-01 (Saturday), because of isoWeek in my systems starts from Sundays.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.now()

print(dt) # 2021-12-27 12:57:57.004108

last_day_of_week = get_ldow(dt)
print(last_day_of_week) # 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000
```

How `get_ldow(df)` could be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import of datatime can be tricky.

```py
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.today() # 2021-12-27 13:40:10.204296

def get_ldow(dt_input):
    return dt_input + datetime.timedelta(days=(6 - dt_input.isoweekday() % 7))

last_day_of_week = get_ldow(dt)

print(last_day_of_week) # 2022-01-01 13:40:10.204296
```